# Change the Cursor style with Resharper

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

So I just installed the trial of Resharper, and now in the code view my cursor only shows up as an arrow instead of the I-beam cursor you'd normally expect when you mouse over text. Digging through the Options, I cannot seem to find the setting.

Anyone know where it is / what it's called?

Comment: What happens when you close and re-open the code file?

Comment: Same thing. I closed VS when I installed it, tried closing and relaunching it too... Guess I'll try a reboot.